# Getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS on vanilla cocos2dx function taken from cpp-tests

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, exc-bad-access, cocos2d-x-3.0

I'm writing a battleship game and it seems to crash when I tap on anything other than one of the squares in the grid. Here is the function that spits the exception:

```
Size Texture2D::getContentSize() const
{
    Size ret;
    ret.width = _contentSize.width / CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR(); // error here
    ret.height = _contentSize.height / CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR();

    return ret;
}
```

The touch object I use for squares is here:

```
bool Square::containsTouchLocation(Touch* touch)
{
    return getTouchRect().containsPoint(convertTouchToNodeSpaceAR(touch));
    //touch->getLocation().y

}

Rect Square::getTouchRect()
{
    auto s = getTexture()->getContentSize();
    return Rect(-s.width/ 2, -s.height/ 2, s.width, s.height);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the limited information provided, it seems like getTexture() is returning a bad value. _contentSize.width is the first time you attempt to access a memory location on the Texture2D object, so that is where it crashes.

Comment: what else would be useful to provide?

Comment: Where do you initialize the texture?

Comment: I initialize the texture here:

    'Square* Square::createSquare(std::string texture, Point position)
    {
 Square* pSquare = new Square();
 pSquare->initWithFile(texture);
        pSquare->retain();
        pSquare->setPosition(position.x, position.y);
        pSquare->setScale(SQUARE_SCALE, SQUARE_SCALE);
        pSquare->setState(hidden); 
        return pSquare;
    }'

sorry don't know how to add code here

Comment: Perhaps you are passing a std::string as texture instead of a Texture2D?